# Define allowable number range for an numeric field in format pane using getFormattingModel method

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

With previous versions for power bi  visuals api we used to define a valid number range for format model numeric input fields using validValue :

[validValues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn6iG.png)

But with the latest version 5.1.0 using getFormattingModel() this valid values is not working, so how to define an allowable number range for a numeric field in format pane for custom visuals.